# How to enable PHP Curl on linux machine using FTP only

Tags: linux, php, ftp, curl

I only have access only to php.ini file and I want to be able to add curl extenssion to my linux machine. 
I don't have access to terminal.

I tried adding:

> extension=curl.so

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to add curl if only by FTP? 
Thanks.

Comment: "my linux machine" - if you do not have shell access, it is not *your machine*. Shared hosting right? Unless the webhost has added cURL support, you cannot use cURL.

Answer (score 2):

See phpinfo() output. 
If CURL is disabled, you need to edit *main* (system) php.ini in line with parameter "disable_functions" and remove "curl_exec" from string.

Answer (score 0):

Is the curl php package installed?  If it's not you will likely need to get an administrator to install it for you, or you will have to figure out how to install it as a non-root user in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

If CURL module for php5 install(exist curl.so in /usr/lib/php5) and you have access to php.ini, you can add "extension=curl.so" in php.ini. CURL module must work. For test open scripts:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php var_dump(curl_init()); ?>
```

If the module is not installed, you need access to SSH(or control panel) with privileges root.

Answer (score 0):

Could not fix it, but I was about to work around this, replaced the simple usage of curl with file_get_contents http://www.php.net/file_get_contents see also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348490/782168